# How to convert Hexa to Binary in 4 Bits format?

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I'm trying to convert a `Hexa Decimal` number into `Binary`,

Hexa Decimal Value : **01**

& I'm using the following code:

```
    public string getSFieldBits(string SField)
    {
        string res = "";

        foreach(char s in SField)
        {
            res += Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(s.ToString(), 16), 2);
        }

        return res;
     }
```

& it returns the following output: **01**

---

where as I'm expecting it to be **`00000001`** , any suggestions or help would be much appreciated..:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# how convert large HEX string to binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617284/c-sharp-how-convert-large-hex-string-to-binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string hexa = "01";
string binary = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexa, 16), 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```