# Read hex from formcollection convert it into binary

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I have few controls in my view in which user will entre hex value.

Previously the user was entrying characters. Which i converted using

```
Alert = Convert.ToByte(collection["Alert"])
```

Now user wants to enter the value in hex.

I need to read from fromcollection to parse hex value that was entered by user.
Then i need to convert that hex into its binary from.

I am new to programming kindly guide me.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show some code where you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks wonko79 that was infromative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617284/c-sharp-how-convert-large-hex-string-to-binary)

use `syste.linq`

```
string binarystring = String.Join(String.Empty,
  hexstring.Select(
    c => Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0')
  )
);
```