# How to convert ipv6 to binary and abbreviate it?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Example:user will enter `ffff:0000:ffff:ffff` and out put must be like this:

```
1111111111111111:0000000000000000:1111111111111111:1111111111111111
```

I need it in c#
 abbreviate example:

```
1111111111111111:::000000000000:1111111111111111:1111111111111111
```

Comment: So you want to convert base 16 to binary? If so, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617284/c-sharp-how-convert-large-hex-string-to-binary

Comment: its not working i need it through class method.

Comment: can you explain rules for abbreviate example?

Comment: the user will enter ip adress in this form ffff:192a:0000:aaaa  with colon(:)

Comment: #Jezrael if user enter ffff:0000:0000:ffff this then its abbreviated form should be this ffff::ffff

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your particular case

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] hex = { "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1011", "1110", "1111" };
            string input = "";
            string ainput = "";
            string output = "";

            input = "ffff:0000:ffff:ffff";
            ainput = Aggregating(input);
            output = string.Join("", ainput.ToCharArray().Select(x => x == ':' ? ":" : hex[int.Parse(x.ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber)]));
            Console.WriteLine("input : {0}, A input = {1}, output = {2}", input, ainput, output);


            input = "0000:0000:0000:ffff:0000:0000";
            ainput = Aggregating(input);
            output = string.Join("", ainput.ToCharArray().Select(x => x == ':' ? ":" : hex[int.Parse(x.ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber)]));
            Console.WriteLine("input : {0}, A input = {1}, output = {2}", input, ainput, output);

            input = "1234:0000:0000:0000:1212";
            ainput = Aggregating(input);
            output = string.Join("", ainput.ToCharArray().Select(x => x == ':' ? ":" : hex[int.Parse(x.ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber)]));
            Console.WriteLine("input : {0}, A input = {1}, output = {2}", input, ainput, output);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static string Aggregating(string input)
        {
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            string[] array = input.Split(new char[] { ':' });

            int zeroCount = 0; //number of consecutive zeroes
            for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] == "0000")
                {
                    //if last aggregate
                    if (i == array.Length - 1)
                    {
                        //write zeroes if last aggregate wasn't zero
                        if (zeroCount == 0) results.Add("0000");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //item zero so increment consectuive zero count
                        zeroCount++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //if only last aggregate was zero
                    if (zeroCount == 1) results.Add("0000");
                    //add current aggregate
                    results.Add(array[i]);
                    //reset consecutive zeroes to 0 since current aggregate isn't zero
                    zeroCount = 0;
                }
            }

            return string.Join(":",results);
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: thats working but now one more thing abbreviating... :(

Comment: output = output.Substring(0, 16) + "::" + output.Substring(16);

Comment: aggregating not working... 
rule for agree-gate:
if a complete portion is zero then it can be written as 0 and if two or more consective portions are zero they can be ignored for example if we have
1234 0000 0000 0000 1212
it can be writeen as
1234 :: 1212